# DXA & DD4T: Activate json compression

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, dxa-java, dd4t-2, dd4t-java

We are trying to activate zip compression for the dd4t published json.

In CMS is very easy to activate, modifying the templates parameters to activate compression.
But we didn't remember if we have to change any configuration at the java webapp.

Do you have any documentation describing this activation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can turn it back on in your Spring dispatcher servlet XML:

```
<!-- DD4T Provider beans -->


<bean id="binaryProvider" class="org.dd4t.providers.impl.BrokerBinaryProvider">
    <property name="contentIsCompressed" value="true"/>
    <property name="cacheProvider" ref="cacheProvider" />
</bean>

<bean id="componentPresentationProvider" class="org.dd4t.providers.impl.BrokerComponentPresentationProvider">
    <property name="contentIsCompressed" value="true"/>
    <property name="cacheProvider" ref="cacheProvider" />
</bean>

<bean id="pageProvider" class="org.dd4t.providers.impl.BrokerPageProvider">
    <property name="contentIsCompressed" value="true"/>
    <property name="cacheProvider" ref="cacheProvider" />
</bean>

<bean id="linkProvider" class="org.dd4t.providers.impl.BrokerLinkProvider">
    <property name="contentIsCompressed" value="true"/>
</bean>
```